# Birthday problem, Average number of people

Tags: java

I'am trying to solve this Homework:

> Suppose that people enter an empty room until a pair of people share a
>   birthday. On average, how many people will have to enter before there
>   is a match? Run experiments to estimate the value of this quantity.
>   Assume birthdays to be uniform random integers between 0 and 364.

The average is **24.61659**. See this wikipedia page for the maths. [Birthday_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people)

My approach:

- Generate random numbers in range [0 - 364]
- add them to a set until a duplicate is generated (set.add returns false)
- add the count (or set size) to a list
- repeat this X-times
- calculate the average of the list

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++){
        int count = 0;
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        while(set.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 365))){
            count++;
        }
        list.add(count);
    }
    double avg = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average().getAsDouble();
    System.out.println(avg);
}
```

My output is always under 24. E.g **23.6285**

- I've tried to run the for-loop 1000, 10000, 1000000 times
- I've tried `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 365)`, `nextInt(0,
  364)`, `nextInt(0, 366)`
- I've tried `list.add(count);` and `list.add(set.size());`

But I'am getting always an average < 24. Mostly something like 23.629237.

Do you see any mistakes and why I'am not getting the correct value, which is approx. **≈24.61659**?

Comment: Because you don't count the *last* person, namely the one which created the collision.

Comment: Incidentally, I'd like to commend you for a really well-written question. You explained the problem, your high-level approach, provided the problematic code, included what you expected vs. what you got (to 7 digits!), and outlined various approaches you tried to fix it. I think it's been some time since I've seen a question that so diligently checks of all of the boxes that we hope for in a good question. Kudos!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that your answer is almost exactly 1 less than the expected. That's a clue: it tells you that you're probably under-counting by 1, which is [a very common bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Consider your condition:

```
while(set.add(<newPersonsBirthday>)){
    count++;
}
```

That won't count the last person! They won't be added to the count, and so you're not including them in the set of people in the room. You've counted everybody in the set *except* the person who triggered the match -- but they're part of the set.

Just add `count + 1` to your list, to account for that person.